# How to say "revision" (for exams) in Russian?

Tags: перевод

What is the best translation for "revision" or "review" (of material for exams) in Russian? Google Translate offers "пересмотр" but I thought it might be "повторение" -- I saw that word as a section heading in a textbook.

Comment: "Revision" implies editing, or at least rearrangement of material. Do you mean that, or have a more simple "recital" in mind?

Comment: "Revision" can mean the same thing as "review", in relation to exams and school.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The total process is named ***подготовка к экзаменам*** and can be done either by a student or by a teacher, or by the both parties.

Same for ***повторение***.

What a student does alone repeating everything possible in a nearly mad state of mind is called ***зубрёжка***.

The tiny creatively designed things used to bring what remained outside of the student's memory with an object of secret and occasional peeping to write it down during a test  are usually called ***шпаргалки*** (AKA ***шпоры***, plural nominative).

Comment: Isn't `зубрежка` cramming?

Answer (score 2):

Пересмотр has a different meaning with the notion of changing mind on something.